# Base de dados para trabalhar com nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, cassandra

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação inteira com NodeJS.

Os principais motivos de usar NodeJS são financeiro/performance.

Ainda não trabalhei com base de dados utilizando NodeJS, porém tenho algumas dúvidas, uma vez que a carga de dados é grande.

Para efeitos de comparação, vamos considerar os seguintes dados:
**MYSQL, Cassandra e SQLite**
**Mais de 100mil visualizações diárias**
**Base de dados com mais de 50GB de informações**

As questões:
**Possuem alto desempenho com NodeJS?**
**Possuem bibliotécas estáveis?**
**Possuem alto desempenho para grandes quantidades de dados?**
**Possuem alto desempenho para uma arquitectura de banco de dados distribuída?**

Quero apenas saber sobre as bases de dados mencionadas acima e respostas baseadas e factos técnicos e não em opiniões.

Comment: Acho que devias colocar o SQLite também em debate :)

Comment: @JorgeB. SQLite é mais indicado para pequenas aplicações, a intenção é ter em menos de 2 anos uma base de dados já com GB de informação.

Comment: Estás completamente enganado, SQLite é muito mais poderoso e LEVE do que possas imaginar. Tenho visto muita gente optar por SQLite para grandes projetos, pela sua simplicidade e pela "leveza".

Comment: @JorgeB. muita gente, da-me uma referência de peso? Atenção, não estou duvidando dos seus conhecimentos e agradeço o seu tempo, mas gosto de tomar decisões baseada em fatos sólidos, comprovados.

Comment: Dá uma vista de olhos aqui: http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html  e aqui: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: @JorgeB. adicionoei SQLite :)

Comment: @Filipe Vai de MongoDB. É um NoSQL que se integra lindamente com o NodeJS de alta performance, flexível e de baixo custo de hardware.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge só quero mesmo limitar a comparação de 3 BD que inseri na pergunta, se não fecham a pergunta por basear em opniões. Já considerei MongoDB mas eliminei depois de ler sobre as limitações.

Comment: Limitações? Quais, afinal? Não ter triggers?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge não sei até onde é verdade, mas veja http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1621

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge agradeço o seu tempo mas o objectivo é a comparação com as 3 BDs da pergunta, assim evitamos opiniões e fechamento do tópico.

Comment: Relevante: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1323/a-pergunta-nao-e-baseada-em-opinioes-mas-as-respostas-sim-porque-ser-fechada. QUem acha que deve reabrir, pode colocar seu argumento lá. Até o autor reconheceu a necessidade de fechamento.

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta para todas estas perguntas seria o PostgreSQL (que não está na sua lista, mas deveria).

Alguns big players que utilizam ele são o Instagram, IMDB, Macworld, Apple, Skype e atende muito bem nas questões performance, módulo para node, grande quantidade de dados e escalar horizontalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo, mas a sua reposta é baseada na sua opinião, o que não é permitido pelo SO. Apenas gostaria de saber sobre uma comparação técnica entre as 3 BD's citadas.

Comment: Deschamps, veja meu comentário [na outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15292/base-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-nodejs#comment27932_15435).

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito... vejo muito últimamente usarem MongoDB com Node... e é muito rápido.. mais por outro lado... ele vai consumir muito HD.. mais em questão de performance ele é muito mais rápido que o relacional... acho que tu teria que ver pra qual motivo realmente é... mais acho que MongoDB seria algo a se pensar =)

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo, mas a sua reposta é baseada na sua opinião, o que não é permitido pelo SO. Apenas gostaria de saber sobre uma comparação técnica entre as 3 BD's citadas.

Comment: @Filipe, o problema principal são *perguntas* que pedem só opinião. O SO permite que eu responda o que me der na telha (desde que orientado à resolver a pergunta). Se a resposta é pobre, sem referências, etc, *não tem problema*, **vote negativamente** se quiser manifestar discordância. Araan, por favor, confira [answer].